# Python: remove odd number from a list

Tags: python

I wrote a function to remove odd number from a list, like that:

```
def remove_odd(l):
    for i in l:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            l.remove(i)
    print l
    return l

remove_odd([4,5,4])
remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11])
remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13])
```

It returns:

```
[4, 4]
[4, 4, 9]
[4, 4, 9, 12]
```

-> wrong

but when I change to remove even number:

```
def remove_even(l):
    for i in l:
        if i % 2 == 0:
            l.remove(i)
    print l
    return l

remove_even([4,5,4])
remove_even([4,5,4,7,9,11])
remove_even([4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13])
```

The answer is OK:

```
[5]
[5, 7, 9, 11]
[5, 7, 9, 11, 13]
```

What is wrong with the remove_odd() func?
I know people usually create the second list inside the func then append even number to that list, but can we solve this exercise with list.remove() ?

Thank you!

Comment: Don't remove items from a list while iterating over it. That's like changing the wheels of your car while driving

Comment: If you really have to, iterate over its indices from highest to lowest. But prefer to use built-in `filter` or similar.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

Your function is working in another way than you would expect. The `for` loop takes first element, than second etc., so when you remove one element, others change their positions and can be skipped by it (and that happens in your case) when they are preceded by another odd number.

If you insist on using `.remove()` method, you must operate on a copy instead, like this:

```
def remove_odd(1):
    for i in l[:]:
        if i % 2 != 0:
            l.remove(i)
    return l
```

(`l[:]` is a shallow copy of list `l`)

However, I think using list comprehension would be much clearer:

```
def remove_odd(l):
    return [x for x in l if x % 2 == 0]
```

Comment: Although this is obviously the preferred way to do the job in python, it looks to me that the poster is already aware of how to solve the problem by creating a new list. Their question is specifically how to achieve the same using `remove`.

Comment: Yes, I have concentrated on _what's wrong with my function_ question and missed the second part. Thank you, I'll extend my answer now.

Comment: Now it's perfect! Take my +1.

Comment: Hi, one quick question : Why did you do that ` for i in l[:]:` instead of only `for i in l:`?

Comment: To operate on a (shallow) copy, not on the original list, for reasons stated at the beginning of my answer.

Answer (score 6):

> What is wrong with the remove_odd() func?

You are iterating over a list while changing its size. This is causing it to skip one or more elements

Why don't you use list comprehension. Its more Pythonic, and readable

```
def remove_odd(l):
    return [e for e in l if e % 2 == 0]

remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11])
[4, 4]
```

Similarly you can write your remove_even routine

```
def remove_even(l):
    return [e for e in l if e % 2]

remove_even([4,5,4,7,9,11])
[5, 7, 9, 11]
```

Answer (score 5):

Python has a built-in method for this: `filter`

```
filtered_list = filter(lambda x: x%2==0, input_list)
```

Be careful in Python 3, as here filter is only a generator, so you have to write:

```
filtered_list = list(filter(lambda x: x%2==0, input_list))
```

Answer (score 3):

You are trying to modify a list while you're iterating over it.

Try something like this:

```
In [28]: def remove_odd(l):
    return [x for x in l if x%2 == 0]
   ....: 

In [29]: remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11])
Out[29]: [4, 4]

In [30]: remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13])
Out[30]: [4, 4, 12]
```

or to fix your your code only, you should iterate over `l[:]`.

`l[:]` returns a shallow copy of `l` which is  equivalent to `list(l)`.

```
In [38]: def remove_odd(l):
        for i in l[:]:
                if i % 2 != 0:
                      l.remove(i)
        return l
   ....:     

In [39]: remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13])
Out[39]: [4, 4, 12]

In [40]: remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11])
Out[40]: [4, 4]
```

Comment: Yeah. Great to know about shallow copy of a list. Thanks! :)

Answer (score 2):

the best way to modify entire list is using it's copy:

```
>>> range(10)
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> l=range(10)
>>> type(l)
<type 'list'>
>>> l[:]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]
>>> type(l[:])
<type 'list'>
>>>
```

From off docs:

> If you need to modify the sequence you are iterating over while inside
>   the loop (for example to duplicate selected items), it is recommended
>   that you first make a copy. Iterating over a sequence does not
>   implicitly make a copy. The slice notation makes this especially
>   convenient:

```
   >>>>>> for w in words[:]:  # Loop over a slice copy of the entire list.
    ...     if len(w) > 6:
    ...         words.insert(0, w)
    ...
    >>> words
    ['defenestrate', 'cat', 'window', 'defenestrate']
```

http://docs.python.org/2/tutorial/controlflow.html

And specifically for your example:

```
def remove_odd(l):
    for i in l[:]:
        if i % 2:
            l.remove(i)
    return l
```

works just fine.

Comment: This answers the question exactly as asked.

Answer (score 1):

You can understand what's happening if you use `enumerate` in your example.

```
def remove_odd(l):
    for n, i in enumerate(l):
        print n, i
        if i % 2 != 0:
            l.remove(i)
    print l
    return l

remove_odd([4,5,4,7,9,11])
```

It gives the result:

```
0 4
1 5
2 7
3 11
[4, 4, 9]
```

So in the first and second case the for loop uses the right values 4 and 5. But you remove the 5 from `l`. Then in the third step you call 7 instead of the 4 on third position. Therefore it's best to copy `l`, as already suggested by other answers.

Comment: Woah thanks for your suggestion. enumerate() is great function. Check it!

Answer (score 1):

you can try like this ..

```
def remove_odd(l):
    a=[]
    for i in range(len(l)):
        if(l[i]%2 ==0):
            a.append(l[i])
    return a
print remove_odd([1,2,2,6,4,1,3])
```

Answer (score 1):

```
import numpy as np
rand_vec3 = np.arange(0,10)
print(rand_vec3)
print(rand_vec3[rand_vec3 % 2 == 0])
```

Answer (score 0):

Here Another implementation and some testing for performance, the Actual goal is
to don't change the actual list but remove odds number within the same list

### First Approach

```
# --- Naive Approach Brute Force
def remove_odd(array):
    """Very unefficient Funciton, it has to copy the arr then iterate through it, then calls
    remove function, however it does the job, good for small Lists"""
    array_copy = array.copy()
    for n in array_copy:
        if n % 2 != 0:
            array.remove(n)
    return array

tests = [[4,5,4], [4,5,4,7,9,11], [4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13]]
for test in tests:
    print(f'List Before --> {test}')
    result = remove_odd(test)
    print(f'List After --> {test}')
    print('===='*15)
```

---

```
## Other Solution ##

def remove_odd(array):
    """Better Solution, it iterates through the Array once"""
    idx = 0
    offset = 0  # NOTE: Offset keeps tracks of the jumps after each iteration
    max_iter = len(array)
    while max_iter:
        n = array[idx-offset]

        if n % 2 != 0:
            offset += 1
            array.remove(n)

        idx += 1
        max_iter -= 1

tests = [[4,5,4], [4,5,4,7,9,11], [4,5,4,7,9,11,12,13]]
for test in tests:
    print(f'List Before --> {test}')
    result = remove_odd(test)
    print(f'List After --> {test}')
    print('===='*15)
```

### Output both functions##

```
List Before --> [4, 5, 4]
List After --> [4, 4]
============================================================
List Before --> [4, 5, 4, 7, 9, 11]
List After --> [4, 4]
============================================================
List Before --> [4, 5, 4, 7, 9, 11, 12, 13]
List After --> [4, 4, 12]
============================================================
```

---

### BenchMarking